# how to create shortcut for android app automatically after app installation

Tags: android

How can I create android shortcut just after the application is downloaded and installed via android market automatically .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable automatic shortcut creation after app downloads and installs from Android Market?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754966/how-to-enable-automatic-shortcut-creation-after-app-downloads-and-installs-from)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do *anything* "just after the application is downloaded and installed via android market automatically", let alone attack the user by forcing a shortcut upon them.

Comment: No longer true, at least not in ICS. I see application shortcuts installed right after downloading. Like: try installing Evernote.

Comment: @Arjan open Play > Settings, uncheck "Auto-add widgets" and ICS stops doing that

Comment: Actually I like it, @zapl ;-) (But you're right: it might only apply to widgets, if that's what you're saying.)

Comment: @Arjan "widget" = "app shortcuts" here. Name is misleading but shortcut is a 1x1 widget

Comment: Ah, interesting @zapl, as Evernote also provides a 1x1 widget that simply seems to be an application shortcut. That makes things a bit more confusing when taking Evernote as an example. I don't recall which other apps installed their own shortcut, so can't validate if those are listed on the ICS list of available widgets... (Surely not *every* app is listed there.)