# How can my Activity install another icon to the launcher in Android? Like Whatsapp does?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest, android-launcher, whatsapp

I know that an Android application can install more than 1 icon to the user's launcher simply by having a tag in the manifest, as explained here: [Android App actvities installed as multiple icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527263/android-app-actvities-installed-as-multiple-icons)

However, the above solution happens automatically. Instead, I would like to give the option to the user to install a 2nd, 3rd, or more icons for my app by letting them press a button. So, for example, if I were a Restaurants app, I could encourage the user to install a quick access icon to a particular cuisine (let's say sushi) in addition to the icon they already have for the app.

I've noticed that WhatsApp for Android does this. You can choose to install a shortcut that launches a particular conversation directly. So I have a strong feeling it's possible but haven't found any material that explains how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to consider implement a simple widget for this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @wangyif2. I actually already have a widget but I noticed a lot of users don't realize it's there and don't know how to install widgets. Since I can't programatically install a widget, I think installing the shortcut is a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution to this here:

[How to enable automatic shortcut creation after app downloads and installs from Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754966/how-to-enable-automatic-shortcut-creation-after-app-downloads-and-installs-from)

Thanks for everyone who looked!